# How to cache data in django channels and celery?

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-channels, django-cache

I am building a web-app using django channels. I also have a task function which i run periodically ( every 30s) using celery beat. This task function sends data to my web-socket every 30s.

Now, if a consumer joins my channel group, he has to wait for some time until my next data arrives. But what I want is to show the new consumer my previous data, until new one arrives. So i have to cache my previous data somewhere.

What is the correct way to do that? I know using redis but how in django-channels?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple.
to append data to cache simply do:

```
cache.set(<key>, <value>, <timeout>)
```

I hope it works for you!.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AsyncConsumer, you should call cache methods with `sync_to_async` wrapper:

```
await sync_to_async(cache.set)(<key>, <value>, <timeout>)
```